# Implementing sorting of a DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection<Dictionary>>

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string,object>>` bound to a `DataGrid`.

I have tried to implement sorting/paging using `PagedCollectionView` class but it was not working.

Does any one has any suggestions?

Comment: You need to give more information / code samples, how is your binding set-up?, what exactly have you tried with PagedCollectionView that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully implemented a paging and sorting solution based on this article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2009/10/01/silverlight-3-custom-sorting-with-paging-support.aspx